# How can I update & commit with Assembla SVN on a Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome, svn, chromebook, assembla, asus

I'm running an ASUS C300 Chromebook (71.0.3578.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and I want to set it up like my Windows 7 Development PC. On Win 7 I use TortoiseSVN to connect to my SVN hosted on Assembla and I can update & commit from there.

Is it possible to do the same on Chromebook? Also, is it possible to do it with free / open source software?

I have seen some options around installing Ubuntu and setting things up this way - this is not an option for me.

[Edit] I have also seen ShiftEdit as an option but this is a paid app so not ideal, however, I did try the trial version of ShiftEdit and I was unable to find a way to connect to Assembla, it seemed that it only had Git integration.

It seems, so far, there is no software that runs on Chrome OS that functions like TortoiseSVN - hopefully someone may know of something?

Comment: BTW, do you *have* to use a Chromebook for development tasks? What's your case?

Comment: @bahrep no, I don't have to, thankfully, I reverted back to my Win 7 laptop, but I often only have access to my Chromebook so it would have been really useful to have something like TortoiseSVN to use

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to replace your Win7 laptop with Chromebook these days. It will *maybe* change, but I don't think that Chromebooks were designed for development tasks.

Comment: @bahrep so it seems. thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Chromebook several years ago and at that time I was unable to run terminal and therefore I was unable to run the `svn` client. I guess that your only option is Assembla's SVN web interface (I don't know whether it supports write operations).

Maybe, there is some addon or extension for Chrome that adds some cloud IDE-like capabilities with SVN client commands, but I don't remember seeing such a product.

Comment: it appears that for text-based files it is possible to use Assembla Web UI to edit these files and then commit changes within the browser. It's not ideal, but I think this gets as close as I can expect to get to the functionality I am looking for on Chrome OS.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use a Chromebook but it seems that ShiftEdit - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shiftedit/lcgmndephhjcabhhjfcmncnhbmgbkpij?hl=en-US seems to do as you wish.

Comment: I can only assume it may have been because ShiftEdit is a paid app - I did try the trial version but I couldn't find how to connect to Assembla, it seemed to only have Git integration, but I may have been missing something